# Find average date in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have two tables. Foo and Bar.

```
class Foo(db.Model):
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  bars = db.relationship('Bar', backref='foo', lazy='dynamic')

class Bar(db.Model):
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  date = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)
  foo_id= db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('foo.id'))
```

How can I have a hybrid property in Foo that can find the average date from all the bars. I have tried the following, which doesn't produce any errors but doesnt give the desired outcome

```
@hybrid_property
  def baz(self):
    return db.select([db.func.avg(Bar.date)]) \
      .where(Bar.foo_id == self.id) \
      .label('baz')
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem thanks to this [question / answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38357352/convert-datetime-to-unix-timestamp-in-sqlalchemy-model-before-executing-query)

I made a custom type that stores datetime as seconds since Jan 01 1970. (UTC)

```
class IntegerDate(types.TypeDecorator):
  impl = types.Integer

  def process_bind_param(self, value, dialect):
    return value.replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc).timestamp() * 1000

  def process_result_value(self, value, dialect):
    return datetime.utcfromtimestamp(value / 1000)
```

and changing this `date = db.Column(db.DateTime)` to this `date = db.Column(IntegerDate)`

and then I can get the average of that

```
@hybrid_property
  def baz(self):
    return db.select([db.func.avg(Bar.date)]) \
      .where(Bar.foo_id == self.id) \
      .label('baz')
```

Answer (score 1):

That's a tricky one.

I am not sure applying `avg()`on a `DateTime` object works very well.
If I was you, I would calculate the average of this field in seconds.
For that, you can have an `hybrid_property` along with an `expression` in `Bar` that converts the `date` field to seconds:

```
class Bar(db.Model):
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  date = db.Column(db.DateTime)
  foo_id= db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('foo.id'))

  @hybrid_property
  def date_seconds(self):
    return time.mktime(self.date.timetuple())

  @date_seconds.expression
  def date_seconds(cls):
    return time.mktime(cls.date.timetuple())
```

And then use this `date_seconds` to calculate the average of seconds, and transform it back to a readable time format.

Comment: This seems to be the right path for an answer to my question but I get an error
`TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable` on this part
`cls.date.timetuple()`

Comment: Indeed I get the same error after trying multiple solutions based on this method, maybe someone else can help with that one? Sorry for the non-solution, but am sure we are on the right path.

Comment: The problem is that you cannot treat the instrumented attribute `cls.date` as a Python date object in `date_seconds.expression`. It should be used to form a suitable SQL expression.