# Get timestamp instead of datetime object, sqlalchemy python 2.7

Tags: postgresql, python-2.7, sqlalchemy

Is there any way to  query `date` and get `timestamp` instead of `datetime.datetime` object in sqlalchemy using python 2.7?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert datetime to unix timestamp in SQLAlchemy model before executing query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38357352/convert-datetime-to-unix-timestamp-in-sqlalchemy-model-before-executing-query)

Comment: ? `dt = datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 11)  dt.timestamp() 1615449600`

Comment: I'm getting an Attribute Error.

Comment: You will need to show the code you are running to get a useful answer. Please include it as an UPDATE to your original question.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to have worked for me.

```
import time
time.mktime(data.date.timetuple())
```